# Performant data-tables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web, vue.js

### Introduction

I am making a request to a backend and getting a list of objects in JSON. Then I change it into an HTML table (it is a [Vuetify data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/data-tables)) where every object is a row.

Each row contains an array of exactly 72 ones and zeros (`[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, ...]`). They indicate activity back in time (72 hours).

In each row I have a `for` loop (kind of. It is Vue.js `v-for` directive) that goes through that array and loads an image `1.svg` or `0.svg` accordingly, to make a [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga4CU.png).

With 40 rows only, the table becomes to lag a little. Now, the table is quite wide and so it goes off screen (`overflow: scroll` or whatever).

### TL;DR

Is it possible in JavaScript to somehow fluently hide DOM elements (in this case table cells (and rows)) (hide means remove from DOM, so that the browser doesn't have to render all of them) when they are off the screen?

Is there a literature you could recommend? Any tutorials? What to look for?

I remember seeing a Google talk on a list of thousands of elements scrolling smoothly on mobile, but can't seem to find it.

#### Demo

https://codepen.io/DCzajkowski/pen/yPbPqy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Czajkowski Dariusz,

Yes it is certainly possible to fluidly handle large amounts of DOM nodes. The trick is to go one step past "hiding" the DOM nodes and to instead not render them at all.

A simplified view of this process could be broken into these steps:

1. Measure the size of the area in which you are rendering these nodes. -> RenderingHeight
2. Measure the size of one visible DOM node -> NodeHeight
3. Render only as many DOM nodes as will fit in the total plus a couple of extra which are used as a buffer -> ( RenderingHeight / NodeHeight) + 2 = NumberOfNodes
4. Create a subset of your data that should be populating these DOM nodes with values
5. When an action on the page occurs (scroll, click, etc..) update the subset of your data that should be displayed according to the action. Re-render the visible nodes with this new set of data.

Example: If your render a list of height 1000px and each list item will have a height of 100px and you have 1000 data points.

RenderingHeight = 1000px

NodeHeight = 100px

NumberOfNodes = 12

Render ten list item nodes using DataPoints[0] - DataPoints[11]. When a scroll event has moved the container down at least 100px you should update your selected subset of data to be DataPoints[1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmq-KVeO-uU) - DataPoints[12]. Then rather than delete nodes or append new ones, just update the data in the existing 12 nodes to use this new subset of data points.

This explanation is definitely a simplification of what you will end up doing in practice in your own applications but I hope it conveys the basic idea.

I believe the talk that you are thinking of might be this one from Google I/O this year: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmq-KVeO-uU. Start at timestamp `15:45` to catch the example.

In this talk he uses the [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) library as an example. Since you are working in Vue.js this library won't directly solve your problem but reading through the code might provide insight into how you might achieve this. I have used this library a couple of times and it has worked well for me.

A quick [google search for virtualized lists in js](https://www.google.com/search?q=building%20virtualized%20lists%20in%20javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) yields some other vanilla js implementations that might also be helpful.

This is not a trivial mechanism which you are aiming to implement but it is amazingly powerful for managing performance when rendering large amounts of data.

Best of luck!

Comment: That is awesome. And yes, that is the talk I was looking for. Thank you so much!

I guess Vuetify's implementation of data-tables won't be helpful here and I'll have to do something custom. Anyway, thank you for this extensive answer ;)

Comment: @CzajkowskiDariusz I think I have better solution, with table rendered to canvas, so it is capable to handle millions of rows fluently, as there they're not flooding DOM.

Comment: @WaldemarIce but then the table is not clickable, selectable etc., right?

Comment: @CzajkowskiDariusz Surprisingly, it is fully dynamic table, clickable, stylable, etc.

Comment: @CzajkowskiDariusz I just added an example. I do not know if it will have any value for you, but one never knows. It may be useful in the future...

Answer (score 1):

Example of Vue application with Polymer element [canvas-datagrid](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/TonyGermaneri/canvas-datagrid) with 5000 rows dataset.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: []
  },
  async created () {
    var response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
    this.data = await response.json()
  }
})
```

```css
html, body, #app {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas-datagrid>
    {{ data }}
  </canvas-datagrid>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-datagrid@0.18.12/dist/canvas-datagrid.js"></script>
```